# Discord.js v13 REST API Guide Cat and Urban Issues

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i tried following the https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/rest-api.html guide before making my own. But I can't get either to work.

Firstly with /cat it crashes and the console returns with:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getJSONResponse (BOTLOCATION\index.js:77:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Client.<anonymous> (BOTLOCATION\index.js:90:20)
```

And /urban works but no matter what term I enter it returns with NULL.

Here is the code, its nearly identical from the guides apart from the added SlashCommandBuilder and REST.

```
const { request } = require('undici');


const clientId = 'CLIENTID_HERE';
const guildId = 'GUILDID_HERE';

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');


const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('cat').setDescription('Cat thing idk'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('urban').setDescription('Urban Dictionary Thing'),
]
    .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken("TOKEN_HERE");

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
//rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);


const trim = (str, max) => (str.length > max ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);

async function getJSONResponse(body) {
    let fullBody = '';

    for await (const data of body) {
        fullBody += data.toString();
    }

    return JSON.parse(fullBody);
}



client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;
    await interaction.deferReply();

    if (commandName === 'cat') {
        const catResult = await request('https://aws.random.cat/meow');
        const { file } = await getJSONResponse(catResult.body);
    
        interaction.reply({ files: [{ attachment: file, name: 'cat.png' }] });

    } else if (commandName === 'urban') {
        const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
        const query = new URLSearchParams({ term });

        const dictResult = await request(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${query}`);
        const { list } = await getJSONResponse(dictResult.body);

        if (!list.length) {
            return interaction.editReply(`No results found for **${term}**.`);
        }

        const [answer] = list;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#EFFF00')
            .setTitle(answer.word)
            .setURL(answer.permalink)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Definition', value: trim(answer.definition, 1024) },
                { name: 'Example', value: trim(answer.example, 1024) },
                {
                    name: 'Rating',
                    value: `${answer.thumbs_up} thumbs up. ${answer.thumbs_down} thumbs down.`,
                },
            );
        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the cat command since there is a [deferReply](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#deferred-responses) first we need to use [editReply](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#editing-responses) since deferReply counts as the first/initial reply.

```js
await interaction.deferReply();

const catResult = await request('https://aws.random.cat/meow').catch((err) => { console.log(err); });;
const { file } = await getJSONResponse(catResult.body).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });

return await interaction.editReply({ files: [{ attachment: file, name: 'cat.png' }] });
```

I also added a [`.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) to the end of each await, this was just for testing however I recommend it.

Now with the urban command, the reason it is using null is since you don't have the string option's text. We can check for it by adding an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

```
await interaction.deferReply();

const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
if (!term) return await interaction.editReply('Please provide a term.'); // We need to add this check to see if the user provided the term option or not.
const query = new URLSearchParams({ term });

const dictResult = await request(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${query}`);
const { list } = await getJSONResponse(dictResult.body);

if (!list.length) {
    return interaction.editReply(`No results found for **${term}**.`);
}

const [answer] = list;

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#EFFF00')
    .setTitle(answer.word)
    .setURL(answer.permalink)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Definition', value: trim(answer.definition, 1024) },
        { name: 'Example', value: trim(answer.example, 1024) },
        {
            name: 'Rating',
            value: `${answer.thumbs_up} thumbs up. ${answer.thumbs_down} thumbs down.`,
        },
    );

return await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
```

**IMPORTANT:** When you are building your slash command you are not setting a string option. In the `commands` array, when creating the second slash command called `urban` we will add the support for the string option there. ([An example using the string option](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options), [discord.js guide all command options](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#parsing-options))

This is how we can do this:

```js
const commands = [
  new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('cat')
    .setDescription('Cat thing idk'),
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('urban')
    .setDescription('Urban Dictionary Thing')
    .addStringOption((option) => option.setName('term').setDescription('term')) // We first add the string option then set the name to 'term' which is what the code calls for and then the description.
].map((command) => command.toJSON());
```

If you would like to make the term input required, add [`.setRequired(true)`](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#options) which will not allow the command to be ran without entering the term to search.

Once you do that you should be all good! Tested the code and it's working once that's fixed

Comment: Urban is working perfectly now thank you! But Cat is still showing the same error pointed towards `return JSON.parse(fullBody);`

Comment: Weird, it seemed to work fine for me. Try adding a console.log() for `body` and `fullbody` before the `JSON.parse()` and make sure they look correct. If you could share the console.log() for the cat command and we can see what going on.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getJSONResponse (BOTLOCATION\index.js:84:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (BOTLOCATION\index.js:99:24)
C:\Users\eards\RustBot\index.js:99
      const { file } = await getJSONResponse(catResult.body).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'file' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
    at Client.<anonymous> (BOTLOCATION\index.js:99:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: @Izuuk Try changing `const {file} = await getJSONResponse(catResult.body);` to just `const data = await getJSONResponse(catResult.body);` then `console.log` it. If its an object something like `{"file":"https://..."}` then just do `data.file`.

Comment: Also make sure your `getJSONResponse` looks like this: https://pastebin.com/A0WpSkEe. Worst case just use node-fetch for the cat API it may be a lot easier since I am unable to recreate the same error you are facing.

Comment: Found the issue, under `const {file} =` i had spaces like this `const { file } =` as that is what it was like in the guide, after seeing your comment without them I gave it a go and it worked...thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad we got it figured out! Happy to help!